# given an array of pair of points, sort them so that ending point matches the starting of next point

Tags: algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming, greedy

Given an array of pair of points eg

`[19, 11], [11,44] ,[ 98,101], [44,98], [12,32],[44,12],[44,98],[98,101],[33,39]`

Arrange the array so that ending point equals the starting of next point. If its not equal then there's a cost = 1. We have to minimise the cost. eg we can arrange the above as

`[19,11],[11,44],[44,12],[12,32],[44,98],[98,101],[44,98],[98,101],[33,39]`

so here cost is `[12,32],[44,98]` = 1 + `[98,101],[44,98]` = 1 + `[98,101],[33,39]` = 1 so total = 3.

I have tried some solution that first match exact pairs and then try to match nonexact pairs but I feel my greedy approach is not optimal and dynamic programming can be used to find some optimal solution.

Otherway that I feel is to count all possible sequences but the complexity is very high n!.

Can someone help me to come up with a dynamic programming solution

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is actually an instance of famous [Travelling Salesman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem) problem. Which means your solution isn't optimal and also there is no possible optimal solution in polynomial time. Although dynamic programming [does seem to](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/travelling-salesman-problem-set-1/) reduce time complexity a little,it's still NP-Hard.

To see why, we need to reformulate this problem using graph theory. Here, each point is a node. Every node (i.e point) is connected with every other one through directed weighted edge with cost 1. Except when source node's end value matches neighbor node's start, then the weight of the edge is 0. Now create a dummy starting node,  who has a direct edge connection *from* it *to* every node and also *from* every node *to* it.

Now if you run TSP from the starting node, you will get your desired sequence with minimum cost.

Answer (score 0):

If we were to form a directed graph, the problem would then seem to be a graph partition problem: find an appropriate removal of edges so as to leave each vertex with at most one incoming edge and one outgoing edge, while minimising the number of resulting graph components.

```
[19,11], [11,44], [98,101], [44,98], [12,32],
[44,12], [44,98], [98,101], [33,39]


    33,39   
                   44,98
                ⇗   ⇙  ⇘
              ⇗  98,101 98,101
             ↑      ⇖  ⇗
19,11 -> 11,44 --> 44,98
            ↓
            44,12 -> 12,32
```

The result would then be one less than the number of components.

Maybe a search with backtracking?

Comment: Do you mind to write some psuedo-code or some real code to demonstrate your idea?

Comment: @darksky imagining with the current example: say we turn right (down) from 11,44; that would split the large component in two. The southeast component would be valid. The northwest component would then split as well. A similar result cardinality would be obtained if we backtracked and took a different turn at 11,44. In general, though, components that start separate would have independent searches and solutions; and if we recorded specific components' (subgraphs) solutions, we would not need to repeat those searches (overlapping subproblems).

Comment: @darksky why..? :)

Comment: This would make your argument more rigorous, clear, and unambiguous and makes it possible for everyone to follow it and analyze its run-time complexity. Doesn't have to be production-ready code, any pseudo-code will do. It's a good exercise for you also to deepen your own understanding.

Comment: @darksky I will seriously consider your request to "please turn my imagination into code," when I finish considering interesting ways to approach the graph partition problem I described. That said, I don't think you've presented a convincing enough argument for me to offer code (or pseudo code). The partition formulation is clear. The ways to approach it are varied and that aspect of the answer I've left somewhat collaborative at this stage by ending with a question mark. I'll be happy to answer questions you may have.